# Double for-loop to process data?

Tags: csv, vmware, metrics, powershell-4.0

I have a question around processing some data which I am pulling from VMWARE vROPS 6.X.

Basically I wrote a script to pull metric data from the suite API. I almost have the format I want but i need to split the Metric and Timestamp column one step further.

Basically I built a `foreach` loop and then nested another inside but I was not getting the metrics and timestamps in the correct sequence (so I removed it from the code below).

Current output:

```
"resourceId","Timestamp","METRIC","value"
"ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466085599999 1466171999999","cpu:1|costop_summation","4.6296298710836307E-4 0.0 4.5836298710836307E-4 0.0"
"ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466085599999 1466171999999","mem|usage_average","12.678446789582571 15.390000343322754"
```

Desired output:

```
"resourceId","Timestamp","METRIC","value"
"ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466085599999","cpu:1|costop_summation","4.6296298710836307E-4 0.0"
"ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466171999999","cpu:1|costop_summation","4.5836298710836307E-4 0.0"
"ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466085599999","mem|usage_average","12.678446789582571"
"ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466171999999","mem|usage_average","15.390000343322754"
```

My Code:

```bsh
#Call vROPS SUITE-API with Invoke-Rest

#Take all certs.
Add-Type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
 }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

#date
[DateTime]$StartDate = (Get-date).adddays(-5)
[DateTime]$EndDate = (Get-date)

$StartDateEpoc = Get-Date -Date $StartDate -UFormat %s
$EndDateEpoc = Get-Date -Date $EndDate -UFormat %s

#Variables
$username = "admin"
$password = "password"
$secPw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$secPw
$ContentType = "application/xml;charset=utf-8"
$header = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String,[String]]"
$header.Add("Accept", 'application/xml')

#intervalType=
$SECONDS = 'SECONDS'
$MINUTES = 'MINUTES'
$HOURS = 'HOURS'
$DAYS = 'DAYS'

#rollUpType=
$AVG = 'AVG'
$MAX = 'MAX'
$SUM = 'SUM'
$MIN = 'MIN'
$COUNT = 'COUNT'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -uri "https://192.168.0.125/suite-api/api/resources/stats?resourceId=ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357&resourceId=1ef459e5-789e-446b-9852-3dc92c43e74a&statKey=cpu|usage_average&rollUpType=$AVG&intervalType=$DAYS" -Credential $cred -ContentType $ContentType -Headers $header -OutFile     d:\quickcheck.xml

[xml]$Data = Get-Content 'D:\quickcheck.XML'

$report = @()

$resources = $Data.'stats-of-resources'
$UUIDS = $Resource.'resourceId'

foreach ($Resource in $Resources.'stats-of-resource') {
  foreach ($node in $Resource.'stat-list'.stat)
   {
   #Collection Date, not run time
   $MetricName = $node.statKey.Key

    $Values     = @($node.data -replace '( \d\.\d) ',"`$1`n" -split "`n")
    $Timestamps = @($node.timestamps -split ' ')
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $Values.Count -and $i -lt $Timestamps.Count; $i++) {
        $report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            METRIC     = $MetricName
            resourceId = $Resource.'resourceId'
            Timestamp  = $Timestamps[$i]
            value      = $Values[$i]
  }
}

   }

$report | Export-Csv D:\reprop.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split `$Timestamps` at spaces and `$Values` at every second space, and create an object for each resulting pair of fragments, e.g. like this:

```bsh
$Values     = @($Values -split ' ')
$Timestamps = @($Timestamps -split ' ')
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Values.Count -and $i -lt $Timestamps.Count; $i++) {
  $report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    METRIC     = $MetricName
    resourceId = $Resource.'resourceId'
    Timestamp  = $Timestamps[$i]
    value      = $Values[$i]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, its removing one of the 2 timestamp values and I still end up with 2 values and no additional lines. Below is the new output.

    "resourceId","Timestamp","METRIC","value"
    "ef951a38-3063-477d-af32-baa6d2744357","1466258399999","cpu|usage_average","1.9282337965236769 1.9452419329074122"
    "1ef459e5-789e-446b-9852-3dc92c43e74a","1466258399999","cpu|usage_average","2.8392222217387624 3.6437365691508017"

Comment: @Humpadilly The code is *not* supposed to go *inside* the nested `foreach` loop. Also, does `$Values` contain 2 or 4 numbers? And how do you want to split them?

Comment: Ok thanks, Values and timestamps can contain 1 or many values it depends on the granularity and duration I specific the length for. Basically the first value goes with the first timestamp, second and second... and so on and so forth.

Comment: Then simply splitting both `$Values` and `$Timestamp` at spaces should suffice. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, works great now. I will post the full script for someone who wants to use vrops and this collection method